# How can I map a login to a database using T-SQL (not SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security, logins, ddl

I'm writing a program that requires me to assign all permissions and everything in code. I have gotten stuck in this part:

[image]

I just want to do the equivalent of clicking the little box under "Map" for the msdb database and assigning that user to SqlAgentUser role. I need a user to be able to add/edit SQL Server Agent jobs. I can get the settings right using SSMS but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it in raw SQL.

I've looked into [ALTER LOGIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) but I'm not seeing anything that does what I need. I suspect I just don't know the correct terms to Google. I don't normally do this sort of thing.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can "generate script" that I think will help you in future projects. On the top of the screen.

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli oh my gosh that is so helpful! I never even noticed that up there! THank yoU!

Comment: I'm really bad at codes, this help me a LOT.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
USE msdb;
GO
CREATE USER shims FROM LOGIN shims;
GO
ALTER ROLE SqlAgentUserRole ADD MEMBER shims;
GO
```

Also, for future reference, any time you know how to do something in the UI but not in a script, this is what the `Script` option on most dialogs is for - it will show you what script SSMS would have executed:

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the current\default database to a different one try:

```
alter login <loginname> with default_database = <dbname>;
```

Now, create a user for above login created

```
 use <dbname>;
 create user <username> from login <loginname>;
```

And now you can assign roles to the above create user for the login as below:

```
use <dbname>
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', '<username>';
```

Comment: [From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750(v=sql.110).aspx): `This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER ROLE instead.`

Comment: So should I change the default database every time I want to do anything with this user in msdb? In the window above it seems like you can have more than one database associated with a user at a time... is that wrong?

Comment: @eddie_cat No, I see no reason in this case to change the default database, unless you want that user to always connect to certain database by default.

Comment: To create user for the login; the correct syntax is as follows:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
CREATE USER [UserName] FOR LOGIN [LoginName]
GO